# How do I get the "ListTemplateType" through REST - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Basically I'm trying to get the "ListTemplateType" through REST. I want to know if the list is a "PictureLibrary" vs a regular "DocumentLibrary", as noted here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listtemplatetype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [BaseTemplate property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj246143.aspx) of the list.

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list name>')/BaseTemplate
```